# horizontally place cA and cH subband's of DWT

Tags: matlab, dwt

I am new in MATLAB and interested in face recognition.
I'm implementing the proposed method in [this paper](http://uplod.ir/66nk4vrst7hn/face_Rec_paper.pdf.htm)  .It is said that after extracting cA and cH subbands , should horizontally place the two subbands and prepare it for taking DFT spectrum. I can not realize what it means to place them horizontally. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If `cA` and `cH` are row vectors, @rayryeng 's solution is correct. As instead, if such arrays are column vectors, you must transpose them using the `'` operator: `out = [cA' cH'];`. By transposing them, of course, they'll become row vectors and then you can perform concatenation as suggested by @rayryeng.

Comment: @Alessiox These are images, and so the output of the algorithm are matrices subsampled by a factor of 2.